# Session id is not visible inside an iframe in safari browser. in chrome and Firefox it is working fine

Tags: ios, iphone, iframe, safari

In my website, I am loading PageB in side PageA using iframe. Both Pages has ajax call. While loading my website in Safari browser PageB is not loading properly inside PageA. PageB is not loading properly because PageB's ajax does not have Session ID in the header.

My website working properly both chrome and Firefox

**Edit**
In my website, I have Two HTML pages **HeaderAndMenu.html** and **Report.html**,

the urls are

**https://example.com/Mywebsite/HeaderAndMenu.html**
**https://example.com/Mywebsite/Report.html**

I have a div inside HeaderAndMenu.html in that Div I am loading Report.html.

Inside Report.html, I have an iFrame in that I am loading following URL via javascript

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

var Report_form = document.createElement('FORM'); 
    Report_form.method='POST';
    Report_form.action='api/Reports/jsp/loadreports';

$('#myframe').empty().contents().find('body').append(Report_form);
    Report_form.submit(); 

});
```

**https://example.com/Mywebsite/api/Reports/jsp/loadreports**

**Issue**

**loadreports** has ajax calls, js, images and css

In iPhone Safari 12, all CSS, JS, ajax are loading first 2 Loading, From the 3rd Loading, the js and css are not loading properly. So the reports are not loading Properly

Comment: What version of Safari are you using? Safari for Windows or Mac?

Comment: Safari in iPhone 12.4.3

Comment: Have you tried using [this](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/) utility from Google for analyzing?